# custom configuration provider is not loaded with exception

Tags: c#, .net, log4net, app-config

I am using the custom configuration provider as mentioned at the [link](http://www.wrox.com/WileyCDA/Section/Redirecting-Configuration-with-a-Custom-Provider.id-291932.html).

My app config looks like:

```
<configuration>
    <configSections>    
        <section name="log4net" type="ClassLibrary2.Class1,ClassLibrary2"/>
    </configSections>
    <log4net configProtectionProvider="XMLConfigProvider.XMLConfigProvider,XMLConfigProvider">
    <EncryptedData>
        <sectionInfo name ="log4net"></sectionInfo>
    </EncryptedData>
</configuration>
```

I  have placed the dll XMLConfigProvider in  the calling application as well as gac. Still i am getting error:

> An error occurred loading a configuration file: The protection provider was not found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not as simple as this typo, is it?

"XMLConfigProvider.XMLCpnfigProvider"

Edit: Nope

OK, looking here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254494.aspx

The value of the configProtectionProvider attribute seems to refer to the name in the  section and is the type name of the provider itself.

Comment: nope :) , its a typo in naming the class... its a trial project, hence did not bother about rectifying the class name ;)

Comment: OK, well that definitely would have done it. It's not fair putting traps in your questions like that ;-) If that's not it, it sounds like a general assembly location issue. Have you ensure that the provider is either in the same project or that the target project has a reference to the provider?

Comment: Post edited for more info - looks like you need a configProtectedData section.

Comment: Hey thanks Steve  a lot lot ! The configProtectedData section worked :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe

```
XMLConfigProvider
```

instead of

```
XMLCpnfigProvider
```

Comment: okay...as mentioned above, thats the class name, incorrectly spelled. However rectified it to avoid confusion.  The problem remains